# Auto complete Extender not invoking the Web service method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am using an ajax auto complete extender control in my ASP.net page for a text box :

```
<td align="left>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtAutoComplete" runat="server" MaxLength="200" Width="50%">         </asp:TextBox>

 <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtAutoComplete_AutocompleteExtender" runat="server"
                        Enabled="true" TargetControlID="txtAutoComplete" UseContextKey="true" ServiceMethod="GetItemsList" ServicePath="~/AutoCompleteWebService.asmx"
                      MinimumPrefixLength="3" CompletionSetCount="12" DelimiterCharacters=";" OnClientPopulating="ShowProcessImage" OnClientPopulated="HideProcessImage">
                    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
</td>
```

I created a webservice and invoked this method from the auto control extender :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace TestChart
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for AutoCompleteWebService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class AutoCompleteWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public AutoCompleteWebService(){
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public  string[] GetItemsList(string Prefix,int count)
        {
            char c1;
            char c2;
            char c3;`enter code here`

            if (count == 0)
            {
                count = 10;
            }
             Random rnd =new Random();
             List<string> items = new List<string>();
             for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
             {
                 c1 = Convert.ToChar(rnd.Next(65, 90));
                 c2 = Convert.ToChar(rnd.Next(97, 122));
                 c3 = Convert.ToChar(rnd.Next(97, 122));
                 items.Add(Prefix + c1 + c2 + c3);
             }
                 return items.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

If i individually run this webservice it's working fine but when I the run the project the text box is not showing autocomplete options.

Can anyone please help me in analyzing the mistake.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is an old question, but I had the same issue and I found that the parameters MUST be named exactly.  In my case I am using the contextKey as well and my web service method looks like:    [WebMethod(), ScriptMethod()]
        public static string[] GetCompletionListOther(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey).  This is basically what Ankur said in his comment to Monika's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You think the signature of the webmethod is wrong, try this (the prefixText is necessary, I think)

```
public string[] GetItemsList(string prefixText, int count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[WebMethod]
        public  string[] GetItemsList(string PrefixText,int count)
        {
            char c1;
            char c2;
            char c3;`enter code here`

            if (count == 0)
            {
                count = 10;
            }
             Random rnd =new Random();
             List<string> items = new List<string>();
             for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
             {
                 c1 = Convert.ToChar(rnd.Next(65, 90));
                 c2 = Convert.ToChar(rnd.Next(97, 122));
                 c3 = Convert.ToChar(rnd.Next(97, 122));
                 items.Add(PrefixText + c1 + c2 + c3);
             }
                 return items.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: You have changed the param name to `PrefixText` but in the code it is still `Prefix`.. `items.Add(Prefix + c1 + c2 + c3)`

Answer (score -1):

To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line in the asmx code behind file:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```