# AutoCompleteextender Does not call service

Tags: web-services, autocompleteextender

I have looked at multiple examples of fixing this issue, but none of the resolutions i found seemed to work. I even created a simple page to call my service. I have tested the service in the browser directly, it returns data fine. I have placed break point in service to see if it called and they never seem to be hit there. Here is my simple web page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="demo.aspx.vb" Inherits="RasDelegates.demo" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoComplete="Off"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" 
        DelimiterCharacters="" 
        MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
        CompletionSetCount="15" 
        CompletionInterval="10"
        Enabled="True" 
        ServicePath="../WebServices/EmpWS.asmx" 
        TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
        ServiceMethod="FindEmployee"></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my simple WebService

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports System.String

    <WebService(Namespace:="http://ws_EA01")> _
    <WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
    <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
    <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _    
Public Class EmpWS
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function FindEmployee(ByVal prefixText As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim json As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
        Dim list As List(Of String)
        list = WebServices.clsWebService.GetEmps(prefixText)

        Dim str As String = Nothing
        Try
            str = json.Serialize(list)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        Return list.ToArray().ToList
    End Function

End Class
```

Any Idea What I seme to be missing?

Comment: Please explain what you “looked at”, what you tried, and why you don't think they “seemed to work”. Are you getting an error? Post it. It didn't do what you wanted? What do you want? What did it do? Why do you think the two are different?

Comment: I lokked at many peoples post, most say add <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> tag or add Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService Bothof which I hav. I get no Error message. Ijust get no values returning. I will try and get you a list of places searched, I did not write them down.

Comment: Afew i found agian were [StackOverlfow 1] and [StackOverlfow 2] and [ASp forums] and [Codeproject]

[StackOverlfow 1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516515/auto-complete-extender-not-invoking-the-web-service-method
[StackOverlfow 2]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628880/ajax-autocomplete-extender-is-not-working
[ASp forums]:http://forums.asp.net/t/1123944.aspx?AutoCompleteExtender+not+calling+webservice+
[Codeproject]:http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/340271/AutoCompleteExtender-is-not-firing

Comment: I saw i missed the service link in the scripmanager while making my demo page, but adding that I still see nothing happen

>